# How would you launch a browser from the a node.js command line script

Tags: shell, command-line, node.js

I don't know if it matters, but I am on OSX.

I know you can launch a browser from the command line itself by typing:

```
open http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

But is there a way to open a browser from inside a nodejs command line script?

Answer (score 124):

**[Open](https://github.com/sindresorhus/open) exists now, use that. :)**

Install with:

```
$ npm install --save open
```

Use with:

```
const open = require('open');

// Opens the image in the default image viewer
(async () => {
    await open('unicorn.png', {wait: true});
    console.log('The image viewer app closed');

    // Opens the url in the default browser
    await open('https://sindresorhus.com');

    // Specify the app to open in
    await open('https://sindresorhus.com', {app: 'firefox'});

    // Specify app arguments
    await open('https://sindresorhus.com', {app: ['google chrome', '--incognito']});
})();
```

### The `app: ...` option:

`Type: string | string[]`

> Specify the app to open the target with, or an array with the app and
>   app arguments.
>
> The app name is platform dependent. Don't hard code it in reusable
>   modules. For example, Chrome is google chrome on macOS, google-chrome
>   on Linux and chrome on Windows.
>
> You may also pass in the app's full path. For example on WSL, this can
>   be /mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe for
>   the Windows installation of Chrome.

Example:

`open('http://localhost', {app: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"});`

Comment: What about linux and windows?

Comment: I believe xdg-open is the standard version of open for Linux, but I have no idea what you'd use for Windows.

Comment: https://github.com/fixedset/open.js handles the x-platform issue

Comment: You should let x-platform npm packages handle things whenever possible, otherwise things will go haywire for anyone trying to use your package on another platform.

Comment: `opn` (not a typo, it doesn't contain an 'e') seems to be the new kid in town to use these days. https://www.npmjs.com/package/opn

Comment: Node Open is deprecated. Please update to https://github.com/sindresorhus/opn.

Comment: @ctide would update to use `npm install opn` instead of open.