# is there a way of opening a new window using express nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am using `express`.
I knew there were   `res.send`,  `res.render` and `res.redirect` methods.

but is there a way to open a new window?

thanks all.

Comment: I don't understand question exactly? http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_open_link_in_new_window.cfm?

Comment: The answer to [How to use nodejs to open default browser and navigate to a specific URL][1]
 might answer your question as well.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500326/how-to-use-nodejs-to-open-default-browser-and-navigate-to-a-specific-url

Answer (score 2):

ExpressJS is web framework for NodeJS

below functions are used to provide response to incoming request

```
res.send(), res.render()  res.redirect(), res.json(), res.download()
```

opening a new window in browser is not part of expressJS

you need to use different npm for **Headless browser** like [Puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer)

example code :

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://google.com');

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Note : `headless: false` will show you tab open in browser,

Answer (score -4):

This would need to happen on the client side via

```
window.open("link", "_blank")
```

Comment: This does not answer their question at all