# How to open a browser window from a node-webkit app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, desktop-application, node-webkit

I have a desktop application, packaged using node-webkit. I need to open the default browser of the user on click of a link. I am using

```
window.open("www.google.com")
```

but this opens a new node-webkit window rather than opening a browser window. How do I open a browser window instead??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use nodejs to open default browser and navigate to a specific URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500326/how-to-use-nodejs-to-open-default-browser-and-navigate-to-a-specific-url)

Comment: @Tomek: Certainly looks like it, yeah; [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13419639/157247) seems most relevant.

Comment: @Tomek, the link posted uses another gem. I would be more interested if I can play with it through any javascript method. Can't find a way to do it yet

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To open a link in the user's default browser, you could use `gui.Shell.openExternal("http://website.com")`. Checkout the documentation for [gui.Shell](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Shell).

Comment: Thanks.. It works perfect. This also comes in the window object, so I can say window.gui.Shell.openExternal("website.com")

Comment: is there a way to store a reference to the window that is opened?

Comment: For completeness,  you must define before the `gui` variable: `var gui = require('nw.gui');`

Answer (score 0):

NWJS Stable v0.68.0
Shell.openExternal(uri)
uri {String} A URL to open in system default manner.
Open the given external URI in the desktop’s default manner. For example, mailto: URLs in the default mail user agent.

> window.nw.Shell.openExternal("https:google.com.br")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).