# open url in default OS browser

Tags: node-webkit

Is there a way to open URL in default OS browser?

I have `MenuItem` and want to open certain URL whenever user clicks this item:

```
var item = new gui.MenuItem({
  label: 'Shortcut',
  click: function(){
    //here i want OS to open some URL 
  } 
});
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077770/window-location-href-and-window-open-methods-in-javascript

Comment: @NicolasHenrard nope. I'm asking about node-webkit specific stuff

Comment: Duplicate... : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19157659/how-to-open-a-browser-window-from-a-node-webkit-app

Comment: OK, final answer in this case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can proceed like that:

```
gui.Shell.openExternal("http://website.com")
```

See the documentation here: https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Shell

See also [How to open a browser window from a node-webkit app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19157659/how-to-open-a-browser-window-from-a-node-webkit-app) for more informations.