# Node.js: How to open an image window on server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, server

I'm developing a node.js application and I'd like to know if this is possible and if so, how: After I start the server, the node.js should open a new window on the server side and show an image generated from the code.

Comment: with the right combination of software, almost anything is possible

Comment: @eko See open module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Its not good approach to open any window on server side, as server is going to accessed by various users.**

But if you want to do so, you can use [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module of nodejs and execute that image with extension.

> Example

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec,
    child;

child = exec('<image with location & extension>',
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('Image opened');
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

> Hello world example with express.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    var exec = require('child_process').exec,
    child;

    child = exec('a.jpg',
      function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('Image opened');
        if (error !== null) {
          console.log('exec error: ' + error);
        }
    });

  res.send('Hello World!');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Having multiple users isn't a problem, as I'm going to open oly one image that is visible when the server is running.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [open](https://github.com/pwnall/node-open) to open in browser, with image url.

```
var open = require('open');

open('http://127.0.0.1/yourimage.png');
```

Or maybe use [Node-Webkit](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/) rather nodejs.

**Full code :**

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    http = require('http'),
    url = require('url'),
    open = require('open');


http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var request = url.parse(req.url, true);
    var action = request.pathname;

    if (action == '/yourimage.png') {
        var img = fs.readFileSync('./yourimage.png');
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'image/png'
        });
        res.end(img, 'binary');
    }
}).listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');

open('http://127.0.0.1/yourimage.png');
```

**Links :**

- [How to use nodejs to open default browser and navigate to a specific URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500326/how-to-use-nodejs-to-open-default-browser-and-navigate-to-a-specific-url)
- [How to serve an image using nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823722/how-to-serve-an-image-using-nodejs)

## Node-Webkit :

If you use node-webkit you can make a window (with html/css).

[image: Presentation nw.js]

Answer (score -2):

It's impossible from my experience to open a new window from the server-side (or even from your code in most cases). What I would do is use some javascript code to make the content on the page dynamic (for example, look at [angularjs](https://angularjs.org/)) and display the image on the same page, even if the image is generated later on the server side. 
Another option is to open a new tab from the client side code for that image.

Comment: Nothing is Impossible