# Run project exsiting HTML file after code coverage finish in grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, mocha.js, istanbul

I've node app which use grunt to generate code coverage report
this report is located under and I was able to run it manually

```
myAPP
 -coverage
  -index.html
```

I want that when the task of coverage will finish and the report is generated to run this index.html in the browser,how should I do that?
I found this

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-run

but its not working

I try many ways

```
grunt.initConfig({
  run: {
    commands: {
      exec: '/coverage/lcov-report/index.html',
    }
  }
});
```

or

```
grunt.initConfig({
  run: {
      path: '/coverage/lcov-report/index.html',
    }

});
```

Maybe I'm not using it well I just want to run existing html file from my project with some grunt task

Comment: I think you should setup something similar to what is mentioned under the heading "Waiting" on that page - https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-run

I guess, you should kick start a browser instance, instead of trying to just run a html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open a webpage with the browser in NodeJS there are [some modules that let's you do that cross-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500326/how-to-use-nodejs-to-open-default-browser-and-navigate-to-a-specific-url).

Luckily for you there's a grunt plugin that integrates with [open](https://github.com/pwnall/node-open): [grunt-open](https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-open) .

When configuring it tell the URL of the `index.html`:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  open : {
    file : {
      // Put here the absolute path of the file
      path : '/path/to/coverage/lcov-report/index.html'
    }
  }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-open');
```