# Redirect to Chrome New Tab

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a chrome extension that takes over the users new tab. We are using google authentication through our own server. My problem is that I cannot figure out how to "res.redirect" back to the new tab once the user has logged in or out.
I need something along the lines of

 `app.get(
    '/auth/google/callback',
    passport.authenticate('google'),
    (req, res) => {
     res.redirect(chrome://newtab)
 });`

Does anyone have any experience with this or any knowledge on how to address it?
 Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might want to have a look at this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500326/how-to-use-nodejs-to-open-default-browser-and-navigate-to-a-specific-url

Comment: You have to do this on the client; have the extension close the current, then open a new tab.