# create-react-app: How do I "npm start" with a specific browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, npm

> npm start

starts the react server on the default browser, which is Firefox for me. I like Firefox for browsing but prefer Chrome in web development for its developer tools. Is there a way to force "npm start" to start the server with Chrome, without changing my default browser to chrome? I am using Bash on Windows.

**Edit:** I used "create-react-app" to create my server and this adds a [script to "packages.json" file for "npm start"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZjk8.png). The script starts the localhost server with the default browser. How do I modify the script added by "create-react-app" such that it starts with a different browser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use nodejs to open default browser and navigate to a specific URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500326/how-to-use-nodejs-to-open-default-browser-and-navigate-to-a-specific-url)

Comment: @MarkC. Sorry I didn't have a proper understanding of my problem before posting the question. I will explain what I want more properly now. I used "create-react-app" to create my server and this adds a [script to "packages.json" file for "npm start"](https://i.imgur.com/j8DLTWU.png). The script starts the localhost server with the default browser. How do I modify the script added by "create-react-app" such that it starts with a different browser?

Comment: Maybe you can `spawn` Google Chrome with your URL?

Comment: You can also use `opn http://localhost:3000 -- 'google chrome'` with `opn-cli` https://github.com/sindresorhus/opn-cli

Comment: shall we edit the question title to mention 'create-react-app'?

Comment: @dcorking Didn't realize I could edit the title. Changed, thanks!

Comment: @MarkC. - it may be a duplicate in the technical low-level sense, but it's worth keeping this question for reference, as it serves the react.js community (where most of the time, the dev workflows are structured,  boilerplate code exists, and other configuration related considerations arise as a result, like whether to eject a react app or not).

Comment: @EliranMalka this is a 3 year old thread...

Comment: @MarkC. - yes, i tend to get nostalgic like that :) JK i didn't notice..

Answer (score 97, accepted):

This is possible with the `BROWSER` environment variable.

You can also do it directly in the terminal:
`BROWSER=chrome npm start`

This is described in the [Advanced Configuration docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/advanced-configuration):

> By default, Create React App will open the default system browser, favoring Chrome on macOS. Specify a browser to override this behavior, or set it to none to disable it completely. If you need to customize the way the browser is launched, you can specify a node script instead. Any arguments passed to npm start will also be passed to this script, and the url where your app is served will be the last argument. Your script's file name must have the .js extension.

Also note that the browser names are different on different platforms:

> The app name is platform dependent. Don't hard code it in reusable modules. For example, Chrome is *google chrome* on macOS, *google-chrome* on Linux and *chrome* on Windows.

Comment: The link to the advanced configuration docs has since changed. It is now https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/advanced-configuration

Comment: Because I wasted a bunch of time on it, for OS X: BROWSER="google chrome"

Comment: @sshevlyagin The second quote says exactly that.

Comment: @Abbe sorry, I thought when I tried it I needed the quotations around google chrome. Looks like I don't.

Comment: On Mac, You can also set it to Chrome Canary via `BROWSER=google chrome canary`

Comment: For those who are using linux set default browser like this : ```BROWSER=google-chrome-stable```

Comment: I wanted to Firefox on the web, and I had to use `BROWSER="/Applications/Firefox.app"` to get that. Just `BROWSER=firefox` would startup Parallels instead.

Comment: Use chromium with this: `BROWSER=chromium-browser`

Comment: OP is tagged `windows` which is also my case and as using powershell, the suggested solution is not applicable. .env file was the king in my case

Comment: CRA broke this when updating "open" library dependency. this PR fixes it, but still has not been merged https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/11878

Comment: How to make it open in a particular chrome profile?

Answer (score 58):

As you have mentioned that you are using `create-react-app` for creating react app and you want chrome to open on hitting `npm start`. Set `BROWSER` variable in `package.json` present in your project in the following manner:

*Replace:*

```
"start": "react-scripts start"
```

*With:*

- **Linux:**

  ```
  "start": "BROWSER='google-chrome-stable' react-scripts start"
  ```
- **Windows:**

  ```
  "start": "BROWSER='chrome' react-scripts start"
  ```
- **OS X:**

  ```
  "start": "BROWSER='google chrome' react-scripts start"
  ```

Comment: I think the Windows syntax is wrong. I get `'BROWSER' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @RonInbar Probably you need to specify full path of your `chrome` executable in windows.

Comment: With remote debugging enabled: `"start": "BROWSER='google chrome' BROWSER_ARGS='--remote-debugging-port=9222' react-scripts start"`

Comment: This worked great. Thanks.

Comment: Not working in React 18.0.0. Is working in 17.0.1. Actually need `"react": "^17.0.1",  "react-scripts": "4.0.1"` Any fixes for 18.0.0 ?

Comment: Windows syntax depends on whether it is run from command line or powershell, but never correct as described here, for me `"start": "set \"BROWSER=firefox\" &&  react-scripts start"` did the trick, even if it wasn't supposed to work in powershell as stated [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-temporary-environment-variables-in-your-shell)

Answer (score 28):

Method by using `.env` file in the root of your NodeJS app.

```
BROWSER="firefox developer edition"
```

Comment: This actually doesn't work for me (on a Windows machine currently), but using `BROWSER="firefox"` still opens Firefox Developer Edition so I guess I'm good

Comment: It's a rather personal preference, so you might want to add it to `.env.local` (which is ignored by git)

Comment: Simple working solution, working with macOS catalina

Comment: `BROWSER=firefox developer edition` works for me on Big Sur, though previously this was `BROWSER=Firefox Developer Edition` . Best try both. No quote nor full path did work.

Answer (score 24):

Using above technique, you may end up with error
`'BROWSER' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

To over come this
Do an npm install of [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) in your cloned repo:
`npm install --save cross-env`

Try to use this command in the `package.json` file

`"start": "cross-env BROWSER=chrome react-scripts start"`

BROWSER is an environment variable, and you can use the cross-env package to properly handle it.

Comment: Just a correction: It is better if "cross-env" is installed as dev-dependencies. So better command would be to install the package: npm install --save-dev cross-env

Comment: I am on `Ubuntu 20.04` and the following worked for me in `package.json`
`"start": "BROWSER=chromium node scripts/start.js",`

Comment: @EdgarManukyan no wonders, but OP is tagged `windows`

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me on Windows running VS Code.

Comment: Installation was OK but still opening Microsoft Edge here....  :(

Answer (score 7):

Simply add the [**env-cmd**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd)  package as global

then create a .env file and write a variable with a specific Browsers path
after that add the env-cmd just in your start script

in the terminal

```
npm install -g env-cmd
```

in the .env file

```
BROWSER= "your browser path"
```

like  => BROWSER= "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Edge"

in the package.json add the **env-cmd**

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "env-cmd react-scripts start",
   "build": "react-scripts build",
   "test": "react-scripts test",
   "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

that should work!

Answer (score 6):

I don't like to repeatedly create a new *.env* file or prepend *npm start* every time with an additional command. You can specify your browser of choice instead of *none* in your shell config file. Type in your terminal the following commands:

```
echo export BROWSER=none >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

At this point you can run `npm start` and be happy.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. The requirement that I constantly have to add this variable every time I create a react project is unreasonable. At worst it should be a switch in the npm start.

Answer (score 5):

In Windows cmd, set env variable for desired browswer:

`set BROWSER=chrome`

Then just run `npm start` like normal

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change the default browser when you are running a `npm start` or `yarn start`, the simplest way to do that is edit your ***package.json*** file.

Many are not comfortable dealing with environment variables using the terminal.

This is what your scripts section should look like:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "BROWSER=none react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

In the above scenario it would not open any browser at all, you are free to choose your development browser and continue your work(I prefer this one). However, if you want a specific browser then you can replace `BROWSER=none` with any of the following:

- `BROWSER=firefox`
- `BROWSER=google-chrome-stable`
- `BROWSER=vivaldi`

Suit yourself.

Comment: Awesome! I hated how the script was opening Chrome automatically every time. I much prefer opening it myself, or using Visual Studio Code launch.json to open Chrome.

Comment: if no browser is opened, how can I see the results i.e how to run it with my preferred broswer

Comment: You know which port you application is running!! just hit  
`http://localhost:<PORT_NUMBER>`
on the browser of your choice.

Answer (score 3):

Change your default Browser setting in windows, if it does not work then open your visual studio code and change the script browser to:

```json
"start": "BROWSER=chrome react-scripts start"
```

Comment: I was trying to change settings on package.json file until I realized this simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

for Brave browser it is `BROWSER=brave-browser npm start`

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved mine:

I opened the application on vsCode, then via the terminal I ran `"BROWSER=Chrome npm start".`

Answer (score 1):

on windows, the easies way with create-react-app was to add  `BROWSER="C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome Dev\Application\chrome.exe"`
to my `.env.developmennt.local` file in each CRA project. I use a different browser without dev extensions as the default one set in the system.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac, this method:

```
"start": "BROWSER='firefox developer edition' react-scripts start"
```

works on `'react': '17.0.1'` together with `'react-scripts': '4.0.1'`

But it is not working on `'react': '18.0.1'` together with `'react-scripts': '5.0.1'`.

On 18.0.1 it continues to open in the default browser set on my computer. So I have sometimes reverted back to using the older React version but do not want to continue doing this as I do need the newer version in some cases and it's just easier to install the most recent version using `create-react-app`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is one package called `set-default-browser` [https://www.npmjs.com/package/set-default-browser](http://www.npmjs.com/package/set-default-browser)

just download package from there and add following code

```
var setDefaultBrowser = require('set-default-browser');

setDefaultBrowser("chrome");
```

Or you can just run this `set-default-browser chrome`

Thanks!

Comment: This packages aims at changing the default OS browser (that is not the question).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using another browser like Brave, here is an example on how to modify the `package.json` file.

In Mac OS

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "BROWSER='/Applications/Brave Browser.app' react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Each approach described in this thread failed for me for NPM version `8.15.0` on `Debian 11`.

### Context

The root cause was never determined, but `BROWSER=/usr/bin/chromium npm start`, with or without absolute path, always resulted the default browser (Firefox) being opened. However, `BROWSER=none` resulted in no browser being opened -- the expected outcome -- which suggests the variable is acknowledged but is being ignored. Seems likely related to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9531).

### Workaround: `BROWSER=node_script.js`

Per [the documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/), `BROWSER` can point to an arbitrary JS script:

> ...If you need to customize the way the browser is launched, you can **specify a node script instead**. Any arguments passed to `npm start` will also be passed to this script, and **the url where your app is served will be the last argument**. Your script's file name must have the `.js` extension.

### Procedure

These were the steps followed to implement the workaround.

#### 1. Create/save a script to disk (`chromium.js`):

The following is a valid script for Chromium on Debian Linux:

```js
const { exec } = require("child_process");

const cmd = '/usr/bin/chromium ' +
    '--disable-web-security ' +
    '--user-data-dir=/tmp/chromium-npm-dev ' +
    process.argv[process.argv.length-1]

exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

*Notes:*

- `cmd` must be updated to suit relevant needs.
- I found it easiest to save it in the root of the NPM project.

#### 2. Start NPM

```bash
BROWSER=chromium.js npm start
```

Answer (score -1):

To open in chrome we need to set it as a default browser.

**Setting --> Default browser --> Make default -->**

and choose chrome if any other browser is chosen.

It worked on windows 10.

Comment: Asker specifically said he doesn't want to change their default browser.

Answer (score -2):

Add script to your package.json file

```
"devserver": "live-server --browser=Chrome"
```

Comment: I guess the answer is that it doesn't seem to work and I can't see any documentation on this solution.