# On Manjaro, where is default browser coming from for react-scripts start?

Tags: reactjs, linux, manjaro

Using Manjaro and running a React app via react-scripts is starting a browser that doesn't exist any more. I recently uninstalled Chromium and installed Google Chrome, and have updated my default browser (I'm using KDE Plasma). When starting a React app via `react-scripts start`, it is trying to launch my old browser:

> Starting the development server...
>
> events.js:291
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
> ^
>
> Error: spawn /usr/bin/chromium ENOENT
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
> at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
> Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
> at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
> errno: 'ENOENT',
> code: 'ENOENT',
> syscall: 'spawn /usr/bin/chromium',
> path: '/usr/bin/chromium',
> spawnargs: [ 'http://localhost:3001/login' ]
> }

I can't remember where this `/usr/bin/chromium` value is set, but I know I have altered it before.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51706882/create-react-app-how-do-i-npm-start-with-a-specific-browser) answer your question? ENOENT mean no entry (in this case /usr/bin/chromium).

Comment: Not quite, I'm looking for some config in some environment file -- I don't remember the path but I think it is KDE-specific. I can work around it for now, though.