# Getting an Error while running npm start in react

Tags: linux, npm

I was learning react and when I run 'npm start' command I got an error like this

```
node:events:371
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^                                                                             
Error: spawn firedragon ENOENT
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:480:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)         
                                                                               
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:288:12)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:480:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
   errno: -2,
   code: 'ENOENT',
   syscall: 'spawn firedragon',
   path: 'firedragon',
   spawnargs: [ 'http://localhost:3000' ]
}
```

I actually removed firedragon which was a default browser of my os (garuda linux)
I actually like to use opera browser and this error only started coming after I deleted firedragon browser

Please help me reach out of this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have started with Create React App, you can use the `BROWSER` environment variable to specify a browser. By default, Create React App will use the default system browser.

In your case, you can try:

```
BROWSER=opera npm start
```

Refer https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/ for more details.

Alternately, you can also try opening your preferred browser and setting it as the default system browser.

Answer (score 0):

What are you running? Is this a fresh create-react-app project or something you cloned? :)

Comment: Found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51706882/create-react-app-how-do-i-npm-start-with-a-specific-browser

Answer (score 0):

When you do `npm start`, after the build, React tries to open the default browser to your application's url.

Check and change your default browser or, if you're using create-react-app, you can change the browser with environment variables by running

```
BROWSER=opera npm start
```

If you want, you can completly disable this behaviour at project level by adding `.env` file with

```
BROWSER=none
```

with this you have to manually open the browser after the build