# How to change the default browser opened for localhost?

Tags: reactjs, localhost, settings, visual-studio-code

I have been working with React.js for a couple months now, developing using VS Code, Chromium-based browsers (ditched Chrome, switched to Brave as default browser) and a Windows machine (Windows 10).

Recently, my friend have recommended that I switch to using Firefox for development, and as lazy as developers can go, I wanna ask how to configure such that when I do `npm start`, `localhost:3000` will appear in Firefox instead of my original default browser. I do not want to change my default browser.

#### Update

From recommendations I have found this other post:
[create-react-app: How do I "npm start" with a specific browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51706882/create-react-app-how-do-i-npm-start-with-a-specific-browser)

Further comments are still welcome XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On **Linux**(Ubuntu 20.04). Edit Your **package.json** like that:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "BROWSER=firefox react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Type **npm start** and Voila :-P

On **Win 10**. Create an `.env` file in the root directory with line like this `BROWSER=firefox` Run **`npm start`** and You are done:-)
Best Regards ;-)

Comment: A new error appeared:

Comment: > BROWSER=firefox react-scripts start

'BROWSER' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1

Comment: Is there some additional setup I should do for the script to be able to understand `BROWSER=firefox` ?

Comment: I checked it a moment ago on two browsers. And it works for me! ??!
"BROWSER = firefox react-scripts start",
"BROWSER = google-chrome react-scripts start",
Linux Ubuntu 20.04 
Today I was updating node.js to 14.18.0, npm 8.0.0..React => "^ 17.0.2"

Comment: Oh I am doing this on a Windows machine, which I checked from the other post I found was somehow incompatible with directly using `BROWSER=firefox`. Thanks for this though, never would've found the other post without your answer!

Comment: I solved the problem on Windows 10
Create an .env file in the root directory with line like this
BROWSER = firefox
Run npm start and You are done! :-D

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to run any command in **cmd** or make changes to any scripts.
Just make default the browser, you want for HTTP file extension.
I have Edge as default for everything, just changed HTTP to Chrome and Yes! React app opens now in Chrome.

[image]

Comment: This does not work.  I know it's an older answer but it pops up in google.  My default is set to firefox and not edge, yet it still launches in edge.

Comment: it used to work for me, make sure the required file extension is set to Firefox. Or it's possible that your development environment is doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I would set the BROWSER [environment variable](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/) in your linux environment instead of the project-specific package.json file (or inside of a .env file) **if** you are using the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) on your Windows 10 machine **and** always want to connect to the React development server from your Firefox browser.

Assuming you are using WSL2: open a WSL2 shell and enter the following command:

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

Add `export BROWSER='firefox'` at the end of the file, exit the nano editor (CTRL+X) and save (Y) when prompted. Enter the following command in the linux bash shell:

```
exit
```

Now, relaunch the WSL2 linux shell and start the React development server again. Firefox should start automatically, pointing to your development server on localhost.