# Browser names on OS terminals, which launches create-react-app in nmp-start

Tags: reactjs, npm, browser

Need windows default browser names for my terminal to specify which browser to launch my react app in.

windows: google chrome='chrome'.
what is it for firefox, operaGX etc? Where can i find the list of all?

My npm start opens opera browser that i have set as default for my PC. But I wanna use Firefox lite for my development practice using react in an effort conserve my system resources.
Is there any way i can change the react app opening my system default browser? (Stating the obvious: Don't wanna reset my system default browser, unless there's no other way)

googling lol. Don't really wanna fudge with stuff i don't know yet as i am just a beginner at front-end.

Comment: _"Where can i find the list of all?"_ - there isn't one - what makes you think there is? (and Chrome is _not_ the default Browser for Windows...)

Comment: i'm facing an even bigger trouble now. "browser" term isn't recognised in my cmdlet.
any solutions?

Comment: @Dai , i have set chrome as my default. And the straight face comment isn't helping.
Can you help or not?

Comment: Look into this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51706882/create-react-app-how-do-i-npm-start-with-a-specific-browser