# node.js- can node js open multiple chrome profile at once?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome

I was inspired by this link [open browser with nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500326/how-to-use-nodejs-to-open-default-browser-and-navigate-to-a-specific-url). Now I am wondering if programmer can open several different chrome profiles at once? For instance this is the capture of the profiles of my chrome setting[image: multiple profile]. `X1` and `X2` are two different users which have independent caches. And I would like to invoke same url `www.stachoverflow.com` at once for these two accounts. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using the [`opn`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/opn) package as described in your link and providing `profile-directory` argument, e.g.

```
opn('https://www.google.com', {app: ['google chrome', '--profile-directory="User1"']});
opn('https://www.google.com', {app: ['google chrome', '--profile-directory="User2"']});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right.

1) You can run Chrome with some user using terminal. There’s a simple example
https://askubuntu.com/questions/681163/is-it-possible-to-create-new-user-profile-by-using-command-line-for-chrome

2) If you can run by terminal you can run it by ‘child_process’ inbuilt node.js module. There is the API (see below). I guess You need ‘exec(...)’ function of ‘child_process’ module.
 https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, however, I would like to use node.js and do some operations with after I open the chrome to the specific website like click buttons etc.

Comment: Does opn package allow to click buttons? Do you consider puppeteer for your intention? It can open chromium and allows to manage pages. https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/README.md