# Open a URL in system default browser

Tags: node.js, electron

I have an electron app using angular. I want to open a URL in the system default browser. I tried the code below

```
import { ElectronService } from 'ngx-electron';

export class AutoBackupsComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(private electronService: ElectronService) { }

   private onAction() {
     this.electronService.shell.openExternal('https:www.//google.com');
   }
}
```

On the other threads, everyone suggested this way but it is not working for me. I am not sure how can I make it running in either renderer or main process.

Comment: I guess the answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500326/how-to-use-nodejs-to-open-default-browser-and-navigate-to-a-specific-url

Comment: all these tried, all failed with "Application not found" system error message box.