# What is the most convenient way to open a Jest Icov coverage report from Visual Studio Code?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, jestjs, code-coverage

Ok, so here is the generic way:

- run `jest --coverage` or wrap it as a package.json script and run that
- Report is generated, navigate to `coverage/Icov-report` and open `index.html`

  - you can have an 'open in browser' extension installed, that way you can open it without actually going into files explorer, but by right-clicking the `index.html` and selecting one of the added context menu options.

I have not found a better out-of-the-box way to do it. My improved version is in the answers.

Answer (score 4):

And here is how I improved this experience:

- Have following scripts in package.json

  - `"test:cov": "jest --coverage",`
  - `"posttest:cov": "ts-node commands/open-coverage.command.ts",`
- Contents of `open-coverage.command.ts` look like this:

```
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { exec } from 'child_process';

const url = resolve(__dirname, '../coverage/lcov-report/index.html');
const start =
  process.platform == 'darwin'
    ? 'open'
    : process.platform == 'win32'
    ? 'start'
    : 'xdg-open';
exec(`${start} ${url}`);
```

- run `npm run test:cov`, it will run your tests, and open report in your default browser.

  - Tested in Firefox, coverage opened in a new tab, tab is focused.

Is there anything that can improve the experience further? The only thing that comes to mind is just some extension, which will add an easily-accessible button to the VSCode UI which will open you a report in a default browser when you click on that button, but I have yet to encounter such functionality.

---

Credits for browser-opening code sample go to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49013356/1762820!

Comment: Very useful stuff. Great job!