# How to stop VS Code from opening browser

Tags: visual-studio-code, browser, server

I'm running a local server on localhost through VS Code using nodemon on my mac. So everytime I save, the server restarts and updates. My problem is that VS Code always switches window to my browser when the server restarts, so my flow gets interrupted. There must be a way to prohibit VS Code from opening my browser, or at least not doing it at every restart of server?

Answer (score 0):

Look into script your nodemon runs when it's watcher detects change and locate call that starts the browser there: presumably you have one in your "start server" script.

It would probably involve your local server address and call like `require('child_process').exec()`; see [How to use nodejs to open default browser and navigate to a specific URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500326/how-to-use-nodejs-to-open-default-browser-and-navigate-to-a-specific-url).

Answer (score 0):

I kind of solved it by adding "BROWSER=none" so my start script (which otherwise only said "nodemon server.js"). But then the browser won't refresh automatically and I'm still curious what's causing it.