# opening a url in browser with the help of node

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, fetch, client-server

I'm trying to open a URL in the browser however the only options I have seen require you have a 'http' within the URL. Im trying to open a localhost from browser. How could I achieve this using nodejs?

Comment: In a Windows system, you can execute the node statement `child_process.exec('explorer "http://localhost/..."');`

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500326/how-to-use-nodejs-to-open-default-browser-and-navigate-to-a-specific-url

Comment: @dom1 the issue with open is that it requires an HTTP URL, Im trying to access a 'non-http' url ie "localhost:3000", no protocol nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use the `open` npm package

Install it:

```
npm install open
```

In your node code:

```
const open = require('open');
open("localhost:8080");
```

Comment: localhost is not based on http protocol. Im trying to access my own system not some website localhost.

Comment: OK amended, try now!

Comment: this is what I was doing previously. I retried it and it did not work. (I have already tried specifying different browsers as well)

Comment: Hmmmm.... Can you show a screenshot of it working when you directly open it in your browser, and then another screenshot of it not working when you open it with the above method via node? That will make it easier for people to resolve.

Comment: what do you mean by 'it'?

Comment: I updated everything (npm, node, and chrome). Im not sure which one it was that was causing problems, but it seems to work now. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Remember to mark the answer as correct! 8-)