# Node.js Child Process with HTML file

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I have a Vue.js app and a Node server running, I want click a button that sends a request to my Node server and opens up Chrome. I know it's possible to open up the application by passing

`'open -a "Google Chrome" http://your_url'`

to the function, but is it possible to open up an HTML file on the server with that command? If so, how?

Comment: Well I guess I could pass it the file path url, I'll try that right now, I was just being lazy I guess by asking you guys first. Edit: Yup that works, nevermind

Comment: This is a duplicate question, you can find solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664605/how-would-you-launch-a-browser-from-the-a-node-js-command-line-script)

Comment: @sorabh86 this looks like a nice library for a better a solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I stopped being lazy and tried it myself, should've tried before asking. 
Just pass the url of the file location to the command instead of the website.